# Login failed for user 'sa' when the app is run from VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have a console application which hosts two WebApi applications using OWIN Self Host approach. One of the apps uses EF6 with Code First. When I run the executable from the bin folder and make a request to the WebApi, everything works like it should - if the database is already created it just returns the results, otherwise it creates the db first. But if I start the console app from Visual Studio (with debugging), I receive the following error:

Additional information: Cannot open database "{db name}" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'sa'.

Anyone has any ideas why this happens?

**EDIT:** Problem is not related to the self hosted apps. I referenced the dbcontext directly in the console app and the same issue happens. I also tried Integrated Security and it still fails with "Login failed for user '{DOMAIN\USERNAME}'."

**EDIT 2:** I fixed my problem by doing deleting the .suo file. That helped me find these two questions mentioning the same solution:

[Login failed for user "xxx" Failed to open the explicitly specified database solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010324/login-failed-for-user-xxx-failed-to-open-the-explicitly-specified-database-sol)

[EF 4.1 code first causes weird (login) runtime errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903698/ef-4-1-code-first-causes-weird-login-runtime-errors)

Can anyone say the reason why the .suo file causes this?

Comment: I didn't delete any *.suo file explicitly but did a clean operation on my C# web API project from solution explorer and it just worked. This is crazy. The same `sa` credential (configured in web.config file of my project) was working throughout the day and it suddenly stops working out of no where. Bloody hell!